# How to remove the static message that appears when opening a Linux shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, system

How to remove the following message:

> To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo ".
>   See "man sudo_root" for details.

Every time I open a Terminal it appears. I upgraded from Ubuntu `14.04 LTS` to `16.04 LTS` and it seems that update made that.

I am using bash.

Comment: Maybe you can take this as reference: [Remove note about sudo that appears when opening the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22607/remove-note-about-sudo-that-appears-when-opening-the-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

I googled that and found this command:

$ `touch ~/.hushlogin`

Answer (score 3):

Execute the below command and close the terminal. The message will be remove from the terminal.

**sudo apt-get update**

Comment: This worked. The message described in this question appeared after I deleted the file: `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful`. After an `sudo apt update` + `sudo apt upgrade` the file was back.

Answer (score 1):

atleast my ubuntu 14.04 machine will display(or run) all the script in `/etc/update-motd.d`(motd => message of the day) directory.

```
ll /etc/update-motd.d/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Sep 27  2014 ./
drwxr-xr-x 109 root root 4096 Nov 30 10:27 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1220 Feb 20  2014 00-header*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1358 Feb 20  2014 10-help-text*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   46 Sep 27  2014 50-landscape-sysinfo -> /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  334 Sep 27  2014 51-cloudguest*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  149 Aug 22  2011 90-updates-available*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  299 Aug 21  2014 91-release-upgrade*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  111 Mar 27  2014 97-overlayroot*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  142 Aug 22  2011 98-fsck-at-reboot*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  144 Aug 22  2011 98-reboot-required*
```

The scipt with lowest number is gonna execute first `00-header*`